# I am using emma for building my project and I'm not getting directories like coverage

Tags: java

see the error below

```
Buildfile: F:\gqmaps\gqmaps9\build.xml
init:
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 106 source files to F:\gqmaps\gqmaps9\out
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
run:
 [emmajava] Could not find Main. Make sure you have it in your classpath
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:138)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:764)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:218)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:132)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:105)
 [emmajava]  at com.vladium.emma.emmajavaTask.execute(emmajavaTask.java:237)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
 [emmajava]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [emmajava]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [emmajava]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [emmajava]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [emmajava]  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
 [emmajava]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
 [emmajava]  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
 [emmajava]  at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
 [emmajava] Java Result: -1
all:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

ant cant find the emma jar files, make sure you have emma.jar and emma_ant.jar in your classpath